# How to pass model data in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I need to pass a model value  item.ID  to one of my javascript function how can I do that ?

I tried`function("@item.ID")` but its not working

Comment: Did you try with single quotes?
Also please put some code over here/

Comment: We need to see more code and what is your error exactly ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the model data into the java script file in these ways
(1). Just set the value in hidden field and access the value of hidden field in java script.
(2). And pass the value using function parameter.
(3).

```
        var LoginResourceKeyCollection = {
            UserName_Required: '<%= Model.UserName%>',
            Password_Required: '<%= Model.Password%>'

        }
   </script>
```

Answer (score 5):

It generally works this way, you just have to omit the `""` otherwise it gets interpreted as string. So you can write something like that in your JS:

```
var myinteger = @item.ID;
```

which renders as

```
var myinteger = 123;   //for example
```

Edit: This makes sense when you id is an integer, of course, for strings you need to encapsulate it in `''` or `""`. And don't get annoyed by any syntax errors reported by intellisense, it seems to have a problem with that but it works out just nicely.

Answer (score 3):

Try this...mind single quotes on parameter value while calling js function

```
function MyJsFunction(modelvalue)
{
     alert("your model value: " + modelvalue);
}

<input type="button" onclick="MyJsFunction('@item.ID')" />
OR
<input type="button" onclick="MyJsFunction('@(item.ID)')" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is pass your textbox ID to javascrpit function and then in function retrieve the value form the ID,

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DatemailedStart, new {id = "MailStartDate", placeholder = "MM/DD/YYYY", maxlength = "40", @class = "TextboxDates", @onblur = "isValidDate('MailStartDate');" })

  function isValidDate(id) {
    var dateString = $('#'+id+'').val();
  }
```